# what is the procedure for creating database in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing an application in widows phone 8,in my application I have to create a database .how can I do this ,I am new to this.please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends on what backend you want, if you are going to store small amounts of data I would recommend that you create an xml file in local storage. If you are looking at something more complex, you can use Linq-to-SQL with SQL Server CE.

The code to generate such a database involves creating a DataContext class similar to this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DataContext
{
        public const string MyDbConnString = "isostore:/MyDb.sdf"; 

        public MyDbContext(string pConnString = MyDbConnString) : base(pConnString) { }

        public Table<SomeClass1> table1;
        public Table<SomeClass2> table2;
}
```

Then you would create the classes that will function as "tables" like this:

```
[Table(Name = "MyTable")]
public class SomeClass1
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly in the `App.xaml.cs` you would place code to create the database in the constructor:

```
public App()
{
    // ... other code
    CreateDatabase();
}

private void CreateDatabase()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        if (!context.DatabaseExists())
        {
            context.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you want an in depth explanation of how the classes need to be set up, if you want to create foreign key references for example, you need to look at the MS documentation.
I would recommend starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).